# Why do we need to check function return right selector

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Recently, I have read univ4-core and I wonder why do they need to do this with the hooks

```
function donate(PoolKey memory key, uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1)
    external
    override
    noDelegateCall
    onlyByLocker
    returns (BalanceDelta delta)
{
    if (key.hooks.shouldCallBeforeDonate()) {
        if (key.hooks.beforeDonate(msg.sender, key, amount0, amount1) != IHooks.beforeDonate.selector) {
            revert Hooks.InvalidHookResponse();
        }
    }

    delta = _getPool(key).donate(amount0, amount1);

    _accountPoolBalanceDelta(key, delta);

    if (key.hooks.shouldCallAfterDonate()) {
        if (key.hooks.afterDonate(msg.sender, key, amount0, amount1) != IHooks.afterDonate.selector) {
            revert Hooks.InvalidHookResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

I mean when the hooks callback is called, what is the point of checking the return of the function? If it isnt implemented, txn reverted anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning the function selector to signal successful function call is a common design pattern in Solidity / Ethereum, also used in ERC-1155 and ERC-667 tokens, for instance. The idea is to allow the called contract to signal success, and make the "success" value one that's very unlikely to be returned by accident (unlike, say, `true` or `0`).

In this example, the hook may decide not to accept the donation because of some parameters (e.g. the sender is not whitelisted) or simply some internal state (e.g. the hook is paused, or the donations have reached a limit). Instead of reverting the transaction itself at that point, it simply returns some other value, and lets the calling contract to deal with handling the error.

Comment: So it's not any gas optimization, security kind of thing, right?

Comment: @BerlinP There may be other reasons I have missed. Let's wait if someone else adds something.